# ElasticSearch indexing with hundreds of indices

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following scenario:

- More than 100 million items and counting (10 million added each month).
- 8 Elastic servers
- 12 Shards for our one index

Until now, all of those items were indexed in the same index (under different types). In order to improve the environment, we decided to index items by geohash code when our mantra was - not more than 30GB per shard.

The current status is that we have more than 1500 indices, 12 shards per index, and every item will be inserted into one of those indices. The number of shards surpassed 20000 as you can understand....

Our indices are in the format `<Base_Index_Name>_<geohash>`

My question is raised due to performance problems which made me question our method. Simple count query in the format of GET */_count
takes seconds!
If my intentions is to question many indices, is this implementation bad? How many indices should a cluster with 8 virtual servers have? How many shards? We have a lot of data and growing fast.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is depends on your usage. Query to all of the indices takes long time because query should go to all of the shards and results should be merged afterwards. 20K shard is not an easy task to query. 
If your data is time based , I would advise to add month or date information to the index name and change your query to `GET indexname201602/search` or `GET *201602`.
That way you can drastically reduce the number of shards that your query executes and it will take much less time

Comment: The index is not time based, unfortunately. That's the reason we searched for a solution that is based on geography. Do you think that the number of shards is the reason for our problem?